# how can I merge two txt files based on a column name and string similarity

Tags: ruby

I have two data saved at .txt in a folder

data1 which is called data 1 includes of one column data as follows

```
from
A0A0A6YXQ7
A0A0A6YXS5
A0A0A6YXW8
A0A0A6YXX6
A0A0A6YXZ1
A0A0A6YY28
A0A0A6YY43
A0A0A6YY47
A0A0A6YY78
A0A0A6YY89
A0A0A6YY91
A0A0A7NQN9
```

and the second data has two columns `from`and `to`

```
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
```

data1 and data2 have a column named `from` 
all strings in data1 should be in data2. if they are not.

I want to load the two data, and if the any string does not exist in the data2, I want to put it there as data1

for example, in data2 the following strings are missing

A0A0A6YXS5 and A0A0A6YY43 and A0A0A6YY89 and A0A0A7NQN9

so the output will look like this

```
From       To
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXS5  -
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY43  -
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY89  -
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A7NQN9  -
```

If the data2 is like below

```
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTLm
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTLm
```

which means we have A0A0A6YY78 and A0A0A6YY91 to be replicate but their `to`is different

so the answer I want is to be this

```
From       To
    A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
    A0A0A6YXS5  -
    A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
    A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
    A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
    A0A0A6YY28  pol
    A0A0A6YY43  -
    A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
    A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL;MumuTLm
    A0A0A6YY89  -
    A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL;MumuTLm
    A0A0A7NQN9  -
```

Comment: I find it curious that none of the five members who put this question on hold claims on their profile to have any experience with Ruby. I thought the question was clear and my understanding seems to have been ratified by the asker. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first construct the two files.

```
data1 = <<_
from
A0A0A6YXQ7
A0A0A6YXS5
A0A0A6YXW8
A0A0A6YXX6
A0A0A6YXZ1
A0A0A6YY28
A0A0A6YY43
A0A0A6YY47
A0A0A6YY78
A0A0A6YY89
A0A0A6YY91
A0A0A7NQN9
_

data2 =<<_
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTLm
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTLm
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTLx
_
```

```
FName1 = 'temp1'
FName2 = 'temp2'

File.write(FName1, data1)
  #=> 137
File.write(FName2, data2)
  #=> 217
```

We can then write the desired result to a third file as follows.

```
FName3 = 'temp3'
```

Begin by reading `FName2` and constructing a hash.

```
h2 = File.readlines(FName2).
          drop(1).
          uniq.
          each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
            h.update([s.split].to_h) { |k,o,n| "#{o};#{n}" }
          end
  #=> {"A0A0A6YXQ7"=>"Myo1f", "A0A0A6YXW8"=>"Pak2", "A0A0A6YXX6"=>"Arhgap15",
  #    "A0A0A6YXZ1"=>"Igtp", "A0A0A6YY28"=>"pol", "A0A0A6YY47"=>"MumuTL",
  #    "A0A0A6YY78"=>"MumuTL;MumuTLm;MumuTLx", "A0A0A6YY91"=>"MumuTL;MumuTLm"}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block (`{ |k,o,n| "#{o};#{n}" }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the definitions of the three block variables, `k` (the common key), `o` ("old") and `n` ("new").<sup>1</sup>

Now read `FName1` and map each line other than the first to the desired string, using the method [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with `"-"` as the default value (meaning that if `h2` does not have a key `k` `h2.fetch(k, '-')` returns `'-'`).

```
arr = File.readlines(FName1).drop(1).map do |line|
    line.chomp!      
    "%s  %s\n" % [line, h2.fetch(line, '-')]
end
  #=> ["A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f\n", "A0A0A6YXS5  -\n", "A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2\n",
  #    "A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15\n", "A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp\n", "A0A0A6YY28  pol\n",
  #    "A0A0A6YY43  -\n", "A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL\n", "A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL;MumuTLm;MumuTLx\n",
  #    "A0A0A6YY89  -\n", "A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL;MumuTLm\n", "A0A0A7NQN9  -\n"]
```

Lastly, we write the desired string to `FName3`.

```
FName3 = "out" 
File.write(FName3, "from    to\n" << arr.join)
  #=> 237
```

Let's confirm that.

```
puts File.read(FName3)
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXS5  -
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY43  -
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL;MumuTLm;MumuTLx
A0A0A6YY89  -
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL;MumuTLm
A0A0A7NQN9  -
```

<sup>1 When a block variable is not used in the block calculation (here the common key), it is customary to replace it with the local variable `'_'` or with a local variable that begins with `'_'`). We therefore might write this block `{ |_,o,n| "#{o};#{n}" }` or  `{ |_k,o,n| "#{o};#{n}" }`</sup>.

Comment: thanks for your message. so I should have the two data set on my desktop and then invoke them somehow ? because I still do not get how to use your steps

Comment: basically the first part of your code is just to paste the data in whenever you are . then we I execute this part `h2 = File.readlines(FName2).drop(1).map(&:split).to_h
arr = File.readlines(FName1).drop(1).map do |line|
    line.chomp!      
    "%s  %s\n" % [line, h2.fetch(line, '-')]
end
puts File.write(FName3, "from    to\n" << arr.join)` it gives me an error like `merg3.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant FName2 (NameError)`

Comment: can you please tell me how to use your code when I have the two data.txt in a folder ? I am using terminal and Mac

Comment: The error suggests that you did not execute the line `FName2 = 'temp2'` in my code. If the files are not in the current directory you need to change to the constants `FName1`, `FName2` and  `FName3` accordingly. For example, `FName1 = ./dir1/dir2/temp1`.

Comment: In constructing the hash `h2` from the contents of your second file, each line is separated into two parts, `k` and `v1`, to form a key-value pair in `h2` such that `h2[k] #=> v1`. If a second line gives rise to the key-value pair `k` and `v2` (the same key `k`), setting `h2[k] = v2` will overwrite `v1` with `v2`. If the lines are identical, `v2 = v1`, so the second line will not change the hash. The upshot is that duplicate lines in the second file may not be a problem.

Comment: I know what you mean but I dont want to discard them, I want to take their `to` and merge it with the other one by a ; . Please look above if I demonstrated it ?

Comment: Latter today I'll show you one way to handle that.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Caveats: This assumes that entries in the from column are unique. If the files are very large, more efficient solutions probably exist.

```rb
# Read in data1, convert it to an array, strip trailing newlines/whitespace and drop the header row.
data1 = File.new('/path/to/data1').read.lines.map(&:chomp)[1..-1]

# Read in data2 with the same conversions as data1 and split on whitespace.
data2_pairs = File.new('/path/to/data2').read.lines.map { |str| str.chomp.split(/\s+/) }[1..-1]

data2 = Hash[data2_pairs]

# Iterate through data1 and build up an array representing the new data2.
# For each data1 line, check if it exists in the data2 hash, if so use that
# value for the new line, else use '-'
new_data2 = data1.reduce([]) do |new_data2, d1_entry|
  value = data2.fetch(d1_entry, '-')

  new_data2 << "#{d1_entry}  #{value}\n"
end

# add the header back
new_data2.unshift("From       To\n")

File.new('/path/to/data2', 'w').write(new_data2)
```

Comment: I get such error,` merg.rb:2:in `map': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
 from merg.rb:2:in `<main>' `

Comment: You can also use [`Array#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) instead of `Hash[]`.

Comment: Ah, there was I typo that I thought I'd already fixed before posting it.